# Check for extra fields

Tags: java, jersey, jax-ws

I'm using Jersey with javax.ws.rs.*.

I have the following function:

```
@PUT
public R modify(@PathParam("id") int id, R in) throws Exception {
    ...
}
```

Where R (Resource) is a JSON object containing the fields to be updated. Example:

```
{
  "name": "Building",
  "address": "Street number",
  "address2": "Lower floor"
}
```

The update process is working, but as an extra measure for our website developers which are using this API I want the method to throw an exception when a field is sent which isn't allowed. Example:

```
{
  "name": "Qcast HQ",
  "illegalField" : "someValue"
}
```

Because the input gets treated as a Resource object I am not sure whether the method can check for illegal fields. Maybe there is an annotation or something I can use to check for this?

Comment: As your `Resource` object dont have any field to capture `illeagalField`, so even if `illegalField` is passed in incoming JSON,  it wont harm your app, right?

Comment: Indeed, my app won't be harmed. But it would be nice for the web devs to have immediate feedback if there was a misunderstanding; like sending `postalCode` instead of `zipCode`. It would be beneficial to have that request fail instead of (partly) succeeding.

Comment: I such case you can very well declare `postalCode` as `@Required` in your `Resource` and failing to provide generate nice error json like `{"error": "missing field", "desc": "'postalCode' required"}`

Comment: Im not a Jersey expert, but see if its helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32304481/how-do-i-use-custom-validations-in-jersey

Comment: If you're using Jackson as the JSON provider, I think it should by default throw an exception on unrecognized fields (unless it is configured not to do so).